# Getting values from get-eventlog Powershell call

Tags: powershell

Sorry to ask such a question, but I've spent 1/2 hour on this and no good solution.

I want to get the latest date from the Event Log for a particular app.  So far, my code is:

```
$event = get-eventlog -logname 'Windows PowerShell' -source mpkLogParser -newest 1 | Format-List
echo $event
```

this yields:

```
Index              : 51
EntryType          : Information
InstanceId         : 3001
Message            : MPKLogParser successfully parsed the log file u_ex100118.log
Category           : (1)
CategoryNumber     : 1
ReplacementStrings : {MPKLogParser successfully parsed the log file u_ex100118.log}
Source             : mpkLogParser
TimeGenerated      : 1/28/2010 11:24:08 AM
TimeWritten        : 1/28/2010 11:24:08 AM
UserName           :
```

So how do I extract the TimeWritten part from $event?

Any help with this and I can sleep better. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use Format-List unless you are displaying to the host.  That is, don't use Format-List when assigning to a variable.  Try this:

```
$name = 'Windows PowerShell'
$event = get-eventlog -logname $name -source mpkLogParser -newest 1 
$event.TimeWritten
```

Comment: Perfect, after more reading (and your response), I like that this returns the actual list of objects that you can then manipulate and get exactly what you want out of it.

Thanks Keith.